# code quick view disappeared in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i'm using xcode for programming objective c. for anyone that uses it, you'll know that on the left are the files in your project, and when you click one once, the source code shows up on the right side of the xcode window. however I have done something im not sure and that view has disappeared and I have to double click each file and open in it in a new window before I can edit it which i find very annoying. Anyone know how I can get the view to appear again that shows my source files contents? I've searched through the settings but didn't find anything.

Comment: Which version are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to grab the splitter (is that what's it's really called?), which would be on the far right of the window with a little dot in the middle, and pull it to the left.  You could also try command-option-shift-E, but then you might have the opposite problem.

Comment: thanks, command-option-shift-e twice did the trick :)
thanks again